# Problems with iOS auto-renewable subscription was published in appstore without having a shared secret in place

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, auto-renewing

I hope someone can help me with this one:

Recently I was asked to fix an app that had a problem handling it's autorenewable subscriptions.
Users where complaining that they could not access the content after their subscription was renewed.

When I looked into it, I noticed that the auto renewable in-app purchase was actually on sale for over a year but in iTunesConnect there was no shared secret.
**Apple states that you cannot publish auto-renewable subscriptions in the appstore without having a shared secret generated. But apparently you can.**

Anyway, of course I generated a shared secret and implemented the subscription handling, which is working fine now. At least all my tests were successful :)
So we published the new version and users who had problems before were asked to hit the restore purchases button (just a call to `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`). 
The idea was simply to trigger a new receipt verification, so that the app could handle the exiration date - this time correctly - and the user should have had access again.
As I mentioned this functionality worked just fine in all tests.

But it still does not work. Since this is a problem in the appstore version you can probably imagine that I do have next to no debug information. 
All I know is that the subscriptions simply do not return as valid from the receipt verification.

I have been agonizing about this for days and days, and I start to suspect, that the auto-renewable subscription purchase itself might be the problem. At least when it was purchased before I generated the shared secret.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Please share.

Could it be possible, that an auto-renewable subscription just behaves like a non-renewing subscription when there is no shared secret in place? Or something like that?
I am thankful for any hint.

Still I am amazed how an auto-renewable subscription made it into the appstore without a shared secret. I think I can remember a time, when it was not possible to create an auto-renewable purchase without it.
But I checked today with a second account: It's possible.

Anyway, I look forward to your opinions

Thanks guys

Claudia

Comment: Use a technical incident to talk to Apple about it

Comment: In fact I am going to do so. Still I am wondering if there is any experience with this sort of thing out there :)

Comment: No experience but speculation: if you're right about it being something inherent to the subscription record, you may need your users to cancel their sub and re-purchase. Depending on what your sub durations are, this might be easy or hard...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, Did apple technical support help you to fix it?

Comment: Same problem for me, the app is now available on production, but still not able to generate shared secret within iTunes Connect, the docs about it seem to be outdated. going mad...

Answer (score 0):

I may have found a solution : in my case, the shared secret button was not shown as mentioned in the docs :

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH3-SW2

This was because, as independent developper working for clients, even if I've been added to the dev team, ITC, and so on, and with all the permissions to access all ITC fields (even Contracts and banking...), it seems that it can only be done by the person who had first created the iOS / Mac developper account (Individual / enterprise).

I asked this person, to try to do the same thing that I was trying to for now 2 weeks, and, magically the button "Generate Shared Secret" was there ! ! !

I don't think this is mentioned in any docs, that's why I hope it may help other people to get around this ridiculously complex process of developping / testing / submitting / and verifying (server-to-server) payments receipts (for auto-renewing subscriptions in my case) and also with the new "Grand Unified Receipt"...

Hope that helps ^^